# How to assign chart title as exporting filename?

Tags: highcharts, export

I would like to use the chart.title as the filename for the exporting module.

```
exporting: {
    filename: docTitle + '_'
    /* filename: docTitle + '_' + chart.title.text */
}
```

Any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/ALungfiel/wvk9cte8/

Comment: You're trying to reference another value in the same object *while you're still defining it*, which isn't going to work. Why not factor it out to a variable like you did with `docTitle`, then use it in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change filename using `Chart.update` function on load event. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.filename
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/b2q3w429/